# ConTeXt: Remove spacing before tabulation

Tags: spacing, context

In my document, I have inter-paragraph spacing on. However, I haven’t found a way to stop it from inserting a space before a tabulation.

```
\setupwhitespace[line]
\setuptabulation[before=]

\starttext
  How do I remove the spacing after this line?\nowhitespace
  \starttabulate
    \NC This
      \NC is
        \NC\NR
    \NC a
        \NC tabulation.
        \NC\NR
  \stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

[image: rendered output]

PS: Should I be using a tabulation? I only want to typeset simple data in a structure like this.

Comment: `tabulate` is fine for small tables, although you can use `\bTABLE .. \eTABLE` instead. Try \blank[disable] for `\nowhitespace`

Comment: `\blank[disable]` works, thanks! What’s the difference between `\nowhitespace` and `\blank[disable]`? Why does the former work for normal text but not for tabulations?

Comment: For some reason there is a hardcoded `\whitespace` in the `before` code of `tabulate` which can be removed using `\blank[disable]` as was already pointed out. https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/9a1b9756939e12e328dea3633d9fe3cbde8f154b/tex/context/base/mkiv/tabl-tbl.mkiv#L1307

Comment: `Tabulate` is better suited to be used in the running text unlike other types like `natural tables` which work better with floats. When you consider this adding `parskip` at the begin makes sense but you can remove the inserted space with `\setuptabulate[before={\blank[back]}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `tabulate` environment can be used within a float it is optimized to be used in the text flow. As a result of this the environment provides keys to adjust the spacing `before` and `after` the table but as you notices even when the spaces are disabled you get a `parskip` at both ends.

To get rid of the space before the table you can use `\blank[back]` to get rid of the previously added whitespace and at the end `\blank[nowhite]` to remove the following whitespace.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\setupalign[raggedright,nothyphenated]

\setupwhitespace[big]

\starttext

\samplefile{jojomayer}

\starttabulate
\NC Jojo Mayer \NC \samplefile{jojomayer} \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\samplefile{jojomayer}

\starttabulate[before=,after=]
\NC Jojo Mayer \NC \samplefile{jojomayer} \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\samplefile{jojomayer}

\starttabulate[before={\blank[back]},after={\blank[nowhite]}]
\NC Jojo Mayer \NC \samplefile{jojomayer} \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\samplefile{jojomayer}

\stoptext
```

produces:

[image]

To get rid of the whitespace for all tables you can set both settings at the begin of document with the `\setuptabulate` command.

```
\setuptabulate
  [before={\blank[back]},
    after={\blank[nowhite]}]
```